# Java Firefox Selenium Headless Screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

for my project i have managed to et each of the individual elements to work. a screenshot in firefox and firefox webdriver working in headless mode, however combing them has caused issues i cant seem to fix. I have enabled headless mode in Firefox webdriver and am using selenium's TakeScreenshot library but that only seems to work in gui modes. I cant find any selenium options that would fix this problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions of things that might fix this.

Comment: please provide code (webdriver configuration settings) or snippet for debugging.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.